# How to load lightbox outside iframe (tympanus)?

Tags: iframe, load, lightbox

I've got an iFrame which contains a set of thumbnails.
When I click on one of this thumbs I would like to open it using this lightbox:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Lightbox/index2.html#page and loading it outside the iframe..

Is possible?

Many thanks,
Luca

Comment: Only if you have access to the page/site where iframe is embeded. Iframe have access to the parent window only if it's on the same server.

Comment: Yes, sure. Domain is the same.

Comment: I just notice that it's CSS only lightbox, you can't use it with iframe, but you can use javascript or jquery plugin to show Lightbox (there is lots of scripts like that).

Comment: Oh yes.. can you make me an example of a cool plugin to use? thanks

Comment: Just a name of plugin to use and how to use :)

Comment: Simple using google search for lightbox jquery show this two pages http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts (10 jquery lightbox scripts) and http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/30-efficient-jquery-lightbox-plugins/ (30 efficient jquery lightbox plugins) you can select which one you like, those are jQuery plugins so you will have examples how to use them on their pages. Probably they will need some modification to work in iframe.